# Criando uma Splash Screen em dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio, wpf, dll

Bem eu preciso mostrar para meu usuário o que está sendo verificado, para isso eu preciso fazer o uso de uma splash screen, queria saber se tem alguma forma de eu usar WPF para escrever o código dentro da minha dll?

Eu preciso fazer em dll por que ela é hookada no executável.

Atualmente meu código da dll está em c++, porém agora preciso implementar a splash screen, eu não quero usar o MFC, pois o mesmo não fica da forma que eu quero fazer.

Alguém sabe me dizer como isso pode ser feito ?